# Made a plain-text backup (SQL script file format), how do I restore just the data (assuming the schema is valid)?

Tags: postgresql, restore, postgresql-9.6, psql, pg-restore

I use to backup my DB with `pg_dump -cF p my_db > snapshot.sql`.

How can I restore only the data from one of those files (assuming the schema is valid)?
Do I have to issue just and all the COPY statements within, or there's a more straightforward way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you created the dump with `-c` and don’t want to drop and recreate the database, then you will have to doctor the dump file to remove the `DROP` and `CREATE` statements (and anything else you don’t want changed). The edited file can be fed to `psql` using the `-f` option.

Comment: I hope there were a more automated and less error-prone way. I ended up restoring to a new temporary database and then transferring data with `pg_dump -a -Fc my_db > data.dump` and `pg_restore -a -Fc -d my_db data.dump`

Comment: Don't use the `-c` / `--clean` option and those `DROP`/`CREATE` statements aren't generated. That said using `-Fc`/`pg_restore` is also perfectly valid, and gives a bit more runtime control over what is restored. The trick always is that the restore tool doesn't know what the state of the target database is and it may not have permission to change objects to restore them to their backed-up state.